# Limit point definition of a closed set, versus complement of open set definition?

Tags: general-topology

I have seen two definitions of closed sets:

1) the complement of a closed set is an open set

2) a closed set contains all its limit points

Are these two definitions essentially equivalent? Or is there some subtlety I might be missing?

Where I am getting stuck is trying to figure out why an open set might not contain all of its limit points, in general. In particular, say that a set is $S$ is open: this means that every $V_\epsilon(x) \in S$. Let me put a further condition on $S$, stating that forall $d$, $V_d(x)$ contains at least two points---so every point is also a limit point. So the set $S$ is open and closed.

Okay, so clearly, "open" and "closed" are not complements of each other, since a set can be open and closed. This makes definition 1) difficult for me to swallow. Also, a set having all of its limit points is not not a property that excludes open sets, making definition 2) difficult to swallow.

Why not work with the following definition of closed/open:

The boundary points of a set $S$ are those where all $V_\epsilon(b) \cap S \neq V_\epsilon(b)$. A set is open if it contains no boundary points. The complement of such an open set is closed.

But there is some usefulness to way things are defined right now, and my definition probably has other issues I haven't yet figured out. There is a lot of subtlety I am clearly missing---that is one of the things I am beginning to realize as I play with topology.

Comment: They are equivalent; proving the equivalence is a standard early exercise.

Comment: Your first instinct in that situation should be to try to prove that they actually are equivalent.

Comment: If they weren't equivalent, could they both be definitions of the same object? More seriously, why not try to prove the equivalence?

Comment: @AlexProvost It was: where I am getting stuck is trying to figure out why an open set might not contain all of its limit points, in general. In particular, say that a set is $S$ is open: this means that every $V_\epsilon(x) \in S$. Let me put a further condition on $S$, stating that forall $d$, $V_d(x)$ contains at least two points---so every point is also a limit point. So the set $S$ is open and closed. What now?

Comment: It might be better if you elaborated (in the question) the points that are causing difficulty. No sarcasm intended (although, I am capable in that regard).

Comment: @copper.hat Okay, I updated the question.

Comment: I am guessing that your main issue is with the definition of a limit point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $C^c$ is open. Suppose $x $ is a limit point of $C$. If $x \notin C$ then there is some open $V$ such that $x \in V \subset C^c$, which contradicts
$x$ being a limit point.

Suppose $C$ contains all its limit points. Suppose $x \notin C$. Since $x$ is not
a limit point, there is some open $V$ such that $x \in V$ and $V$ does not intersect $C$. Hence $C^c$ is open.

Comment: I am good with the first proof. For the second proof, I have a problem with: "Since $x$ is not a limit point, there is some open $V$ such that $x \in V$..." -- how does that follow automatically from $x$ not being a limit point?

Comment: If $x$ is not a limit point, then there must be some open $V$ containing $x$ such that either  $V$ does not intersect $C$ or $V$ does not intersect $C^c$. Since $V$ contains $x$ and $x \notin C$ (in the proof) we see that $V$ is contained in $C^c$,

Answer (score 2):

I am answering the following question, which I think is the one you want answered:"might not an open set  contain all of its limit points, in general?" That's where you say you are getting stuck. You should get stuck there, because the answer is yes an open set can also be closed. A cheap shot is to take every subset of say the set of real numbers to be open; then every subset is also closed. Or take X to be the union of the open intervals (2,3) and (5,17). I'm hoping you will think of the topology on this set that I have in mind. If you do, you will see that (2,3) is open and contains all its limit points. A caveat: Although the definitions are equivalent, in topology definitions involving points are replaced by definitions involving open sets. Be on the lookout for this theme.